# Convertir un array en string para guardarlo y ahora no se como recuperarlo; ¿cómo puedo devolver un array a string?

Tags: ruby

Convertí un array a string con `.to_s`

```
array.to_s = > "[\"hola\", \"plus\", \"hash\"]"
```

¿Cómo podría devolverlo a `["hola","plus" , "hash"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haría con `JSON.parse`:

```
require 'json'

array = ["hola", "plus", "hash"]
#=> ["hola", "plus", "hash"]

array = array.to_s
#=> "[\"hola\", \"plus\", \"hash\"]"

JSON.parse(array)
#=> ["hola", "plus", "hash"]
```

Prefiero esta opción sobre `eval()` debido al riesgo potencial que tiene **en caso que la información venga de una fuente externa** (de lo contrario, no hay riesgo).

Comment: Gracias , tienes razon por motivos de seguridad es mejor JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

Hola una solucion sencilla es utilizar la funcion `eval` que recibe como parametro un string y lo interpreta como codigo, quedaria asi:

```
nuevo_array = eval(array.to_s) #=> ["hola","plus" , "hash"]
```

Para volver el mismo array puede hacerlo asi:

```
array = ["hola","plus" , "hash"]
array = array.to_s #=> "[\"hola\", \"plus\", \"hash\"]"
array = eval(array) #=> ["hola","plus" , "hash"]
```

Espero te haya ayudado, suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el metodo `split()` para recrear nuevamente el array.

Ejemplo:

```
array = ["hola", "plus", "hash"]

string = array.to_s #=> "[\"hola\", \"plus\", \"hash\"]";

array = string[1,string.length-2].split(", ") #=> ["hola", "plus", "hash"]
```